# Creating new column for rolling average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Consider the following table with three columns: `issueid`, `date` and `rate`: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/611682. I would like to create a new column that displays the moving average of `rate` for each issueid at each date. I want to call this column `mse_m`.

The result I am looking for is:

[image]

For issueid 1, the average on 3/31/2014 is the average of the rate values on 01/31/2014, 02/28/2014 and 3/31/2014. In other words, for each security and at each the date, the moving average is the average of the rate values for that month and the two previous months.

Here is what I have tried:

```
update my_table
set mse_m = (
    SELECT AVG(B.rate)
    FROM my_table A
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
             FROM my_table
             WHERE i.issueid = A.issueid
             AND i.[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-2,A.[date]) AND A.[date]) B 
    GROUP BY A.issueid, A.[date], A.rate)
from my_table i
```

However I get the following error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So, does your table already has the new column or you want to create a new column?

Comment: Yes, the table already has that column with NULL values. Thanks for your help in the previous post by the way. This is a follow-up question to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.issueid, A.[date], A.rate, AVG(B.rate) mse_m
    FROM dbo.my_table A
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
                 FROM dbo.my_table
                 WHERE issueid = A.issueid
                 AND [date] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-2,A.[date]) AND A.[date]) B 
    GROUP BY A.issueid, A.[date], A.rate
)
UPDATE A
SET A.mse_m = B.mse_m
FROM dbo.my_table A
INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON A.issueid = B.issueid
    AND A.[date] = B.[date]
    AND A.rate = B.rate;
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! Would you please be able to tell me why my query didn't work? I am a beginner at SQL, so please bear with me.

Comment: @Mariam Well, the main reason would be that you were trying to assign a single value to `mse_m` that was equal to multiple rows. You were using `SET mse_m = (some select that returns more than 1 row)`, that's the same as saying: "For that particular row of `mse_m` I want to assign the value of those multiple rows".

Comment: Ok got it, thanks!! And what is the meaning of `; WITH CTE AS`?

Comment: @Mariam That's just a [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thanks again, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Follow-up question please: how about if, for each date, the `rate` value is the same for all `issueid`. Is it possible to compute the rolling average without taking into account issueid in the query?